# Jmeter - Can I include two .P12 Cerificates to a Testplan?

Tags: ssl, jmeter

I am creating a script that both sends and answers requests. Both are using different endpoints and a different .p12 certificate.

I can add both in the system.properties file or load them using the SSL Manager. However the script only uses the last one, so will not run properly.

So how can I get both certificates in the keystore and jmeter to use them ?

Answer (score 0):

.p12 is not a "certificate", it's a [Java Keystore in PKCS12 format](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/ggfhb/index.html) and it can contain > 1 certificate.

See i.e. [How to Import CA cert to pkcs12](https://superuser.com/questions/433236/how-to-import-ca-cert-to-pkcs12) topic to learn how to do it.

Once done you can add a [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) to provide certificate aliases and [Keystore Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration) to encrypt the outgoing requests with the certificates.

More information: [How to Use Multiple Certificates When Load Testing Secure Websites](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-multiple-certificates-when-load-testing)

Comment: Uhmm at the moment my Jmeter doesnot accept the .p12 files anymore ... it did before...

Comment: Now I get : 2022-09-30 13:15:59,862 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: JmeterKeyStore Location: <server>\<folder>\Jmeter\Backup\xxxxxxxxxxx.p12 type pkcs12 
2022-09-30 13:15:59,862 ERROR o.a.j.g.a.ActionRouter: Error processing org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.SSLManagerCommand@1e2a6e2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create keystore: pkcs12  not found

Comment: This happens when I try to load them with the SSL Manager.